# Selecting and deleting rows based on textbox input to SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

So i have a button that is supposed to search a db from sql based on the input from a textbox, select the entire row if successful, and then delete the row.

this is my code so far,

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data source=.; initial catalog = saleCo; integrated security=true")
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim deleteProduct = New SqlCommand()

    Dim deleteProductcmd As String = "DELETE FROM PRODUCT WHERE P_CODE = @p_code"

    deleteProduct.Connection = myConnection
    deleteProduct.CommandText = deleteProductcmd

    deleteProduct.Parameters.Remove("@p_code", TextBox2.Text)

    deleteProduct.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()
```

the code seems to be having a problem with the line "deleteProduct.Parameters.Remove"
mostly the ".Remove" part. any ways to change this to somehow work?

Comment: Why do you want to "Remove" if your intend to "Add" an input (TextBox2.Text)?

Comment: @Filburt the intent was to remove a row within the database. This was to be done by typing a product code into a textbox, and clicking the delete button. From there, the code would search the table, look for the row based on the text within the textbox, and then delete the row. Also thank you for fixing the question. i couldnt seem to fix the view myself.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
deleteProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_code", TextBox2.Text)
```

Check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i literally did this as a test right after i asked the question and it worked, im so sorry for the small time wasted XD

Comment: Not blunt enough, @obl. Almran, accept this as the answer since it solved your problem :)